# bluemix secure-gateway docker client disconnecting or simply not connecting

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, gateway, secure-gateway

Trying to use the Bluemix secure-gateway service in order to connect devices from internet to intranet.
I am using the free version of Bluemix, as well as docker (1.10.2) running on Centos 7 and RHEL 7 machines.

I am facing two issues:

- When connecting the client using the command provided by bluemix, sometimes connection does not take place, and I have to keep trying (many many times) until that works out. Error message: `[ERROR] (Client PID 1) The response is code: ENOTFOUND, message: getaddrinfo`
- Even when a client is connected to Bluemix, the connection is sometimes dropped.

Not sure how to debug and/or resolve, please let me know if I can provide more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are saying that the connection is not stable.
My suggestion is that you can try native client instead of docker client.

Comment: Getting the following error on RHEL7: file / from install of ibm-securegateway-client-1.4.1-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-20.el7.x86_64

Comment: Please try --force option for RH 7 or greater version.